# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction doesnt return a receipt

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I am trying to transfer some funds using a NodeJS application. The code I am using is:

```
async function transfer(to, amountToSend) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_serverEthAccount.address);

        web3.eth.getBalance(_serverEthAccount.address, async (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject();
            }
            let balance = web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether');
            console.log('Current Server Balance:', balance);

            if (balance < amountToSend) {
                console.error('Insufficient funds!');
                return reject();
            }

            let details = {
                "to": to,
                value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
                gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
                gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
                "nonce": nonce,
                "chainId": 4 // EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, rinkeby: 4
            };

            const transaction = new EthereumTx(details, { chain: 'rinkeby' });
            let privateKey = _serverEthAccount.privateKey.split('0x');
            let privKey = Buffer.from(privateKey[1], 'hex');
            transaction.sign(privKey);

            const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();

            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex'))
                .on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
                    const url = `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/${hash}`; // TODO: Change this for prod
                    console.log('Transaction URL: ', url);
                    console.log('TX: ', hash);
                    resolve(hash);
                })
                .on('receipt', (rec) => {
                    console.log('Receipt', rec);
                    resolve(rec);
                })
                .on('confirmation', (confirmationNum, rec) => {
                    console.log('Confirmation Received: ', confirmationNum);
                    resolve({ confirmationNum, rec });
                })
                .on('error', (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject();
                });
        });
    });
}
```

What I am noticing here is that I can successfully execute this code. The `on('transactionHash)` event is fired and I get that, although there is nothing on Etherscan. I never get a receipt and no transaction is made.

I have spent some time Googling the issue and have also tried changing the line creating the transaction object to `const transaction = new EthereumTx(details, { chain: 'rinkeby', hardfork: 'istanbul' });`, but I am still getting the exact same result.

Other information that might be relevant is that I am Infura.

```
const ethNetwork = 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/{key}';
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethNetwork));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!